# double free or corruption run-time error while running pcl::MovingLeastSquares code on ARM processor

Tags: c++, ubuntu, arm, point-cloud-library

I am having run-time problems running moving least squares code on ARM processor running Ubuntu 13.04, 
manual compile the latest pcl 1.7.2 from github.

There's a double free error that crashed in line 266 of
surface/include/pcl/surface/impl/mls.hpp

Other related packages:

- LibBoost version 1.49.0.1
- FLANN version 1.7.1-4
- Eigen  3.1.2-1

The same code runs correctly on a regular PC (64bit Ubuntu 12.04).

I grabbed and modified the code from:
http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/resampling.php

Here is the bare-bone code that I end up running:

```
#include <pcl/point_types.h> 
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>

#include <pcl/kdtree/kdtree_flann.h>
#include <pcl/surface/mls.h>

using namespace pcl;
using namespace pcl::io;

// ######################################################################
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  // Load input file into a PointCloud<T> with an appropriate type
  PointCloud<PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud (new PointCloud<PointXYZ> ());
  pcl::io::loadPCDFile (argv[1], *cloud);

  // Create a KD-Tree
  pcl::search::KdTree<PointXYZ>::Ptr 
    tree (new pcl::search::KdTree<PointXYZ>);

  // Output has the PointNormal type 
  // in order to store the normals calculated by MLS
  PointCloud<PointNormal> mls_points;

  // Init object (second point type is for the normals, even if unused)
  pcl::MovingLeastSquares<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::PointNormal> mls;

  mls.setComputeNormals (true);

  // Set parameters
  mls.setInputCloud (cloud);
  mls.setPolynomialFit (true);
  mls.setSearchMethod (tree);
  mls.setSearchRadius (0.03);

  // Reconstruct CRASH IN LINE BELOW
  mls.process (mls_points);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Below is the gdb trace. The code crashed in the mls.process line:

```
randall@odroid:~/pcl_project/build$ gdb --args ../bin/a.out ~/Downloads/pcl-master1.7.2/test/bun0.pcd 
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.5.91.20130417-cvs-ubuntu
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "arm-linux-gnueabihf".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /home/randall/pcl_project/bin/a.out ...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/randall/pcl_project/bin/a.out /home/randall/Downloads/pcl-master1.7.2/test/bun0.pcd
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
0xaee3e328 in ?? () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
*** Error in `/home/randall/pcl_project/bin/a.out': double free or corruption (out): 0x002f1900 ***

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
__libc_do_syscall () at ../ports/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm/libc-do-syscall.S:44
44  ../ports/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm/libc-do-syscall.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  __libc_do_syscall () at ../ports/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm/libc-do-syscall.S:44
#1  0xb2d8b5fe in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
#2  0xb2d8de1a in __GI_abort () at abort.c:90
#3  0xb2db19ec in __libc_message (do_abort=2, fmt=0xb2e307c0 "*** Error in `%s': %s: 0x%s ***\n") at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/libc_fatal.c:199
#4  0xb2db8752 in malloc_printerr (action=3, str=0xb2e30938 "double free or corruption (out)", ptr=<optimized out>) at malloc.c:4923
#5  0xb2db9192 in _int_free (av=<optimized out>, p=0x2f18f8, have_lock=0) at malloc.c:3779
#6  0xb36b61e2 in aligned_free (ptr=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/util/Memory.h:227
#7  conditional_aligned_free<true> (ptr=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/util/Memory.h:299
#8  conditional_aligned_delete_auto<double, true> (ptr=<optimized out>, size=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/util/Memory.h:425
#9  ~DenseStorage (this=0xbeffe148, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:200
#10 ~PlainObjectBase (this=0xbeffe148, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:72
#11 ~Matrix (this=0xbeffe148, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:127
#12 ~LLT (this=0xbeffe148, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Cholesky/LLT.h:50
#13 pcl::MovingLeastSquares<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::PointNormal>::computeMLSPointNormal (this=this@entry=0xbeffe5e0, index=0, nn_indices=..., nn_sqr_dists=..., 
    projected_points=..., projected_points_normals=..., corresponding_input_indices=..., mls_result=...)
    at /home/randall/Downloads/pcl-master1.7.2/surface/include/pcl/surface/impl/mls.hpp:266
#14 0xb36b6d78 in pcl::MovingLeastSquares<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::PointNormal>::performProcessing (this=0xbeffe5e0, output=...)
    at /home/randall/Downloads/pcl-master1.7.2/surface/include/pcl/surface/impl/mls.hpp:489
#15 0xb36860d2 in pcl::MovingLeastSquares<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::PointNormal>::process (this=0xbeffe5e0, output=...)
    at /home/randall/Downloads/pcl-master1.7.2/surface/include/pcl/surface/impl/mls.hpp:133
#16 0x001d28c4 in main (argc=2, argv=0xbefff1a4) at /home/randall/pcl_project/src/main.C:67
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you find any solution of "SIGABRT, libc-do-syscall.S: No such file or directory"? I am running my code on ARM architecture & getting the same SIGABRT. If you find any solution, please share.

Answer (score 3):

As per Nizar Sallem's suggestion I disabled vectorization 
(set it to 0 say in pcl_config.h since that one is included almost every where) while in debug mode.
==> http://www.pcl-users.org/double-free-or-corruption-error-in-pcl-MovingLeastSquares-on-ARM-processor-td4033241.html#a4033425

Here's what I did:

I added to pcl-master1.7.2/CMakeList.txt

```
add_definitions(-DEIGEN_DISABLE_UNALIGNED_ARRAY_ASSERT 
                      -DEIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE) 
add_definitions(-DEIGEN_DONT_ALIGN)
```

after the definitions of Eigen:

```
# Eigen (required) 
find_package(Eigen REQUIRED) 
include_directories(SYSTEM ${EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIRS}) 
add_definitions(-DEIGEN_USE_NEW_STDVECTOR 
                -DEIGEN_YES_I_KNOW_SPARSE_MODULE_IS_NOT_STABLE_YET)
```

I also added to pcl_config.h.in

```
#define EIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE 1 
#define EIGEN_DONT_ALIGN 1
```

on line 15 after:

```
#define PCL_VERSION_COMPARE(OP,MAJ,MIN,PATCH) \
      (PCL_VERSION OP PCL_VERSION_CALC(MAJ,MIN,PATCH))
```

One or both of these two additions does the trick.